# Using Google Docs API ( Gdata) from Java web application to upload doc

Tags: java, gdata-api

I'm working on a **web-based** application which would allow users to upload a Word document to Google Docs using the GData Java API.

( I came across [this](http://blog.essaytagger.com/2011/07/how-to-upload-file-to-google-docs-when.html) blog where I found out that I could actually use a byte array to upload a doc instead of using a **File** )

I'm using Netbeans + JDK 1.6

The relevant code in my servlet:

```
DocsService docsService = new DocsService("care.udhc.co.in");                
try {
    docsService.setUserCredentials("sbose78@gmail.com", "*******");      

    DocumentListEntry newDocument = new DocumentListEntry();

    String s="hello bose";
    byte byteData[]=s.getBytes();

    // Load the byte array into a MediaSource
    MediaByteArraySource mediaSource = new MediaByteArraySource(byteData, MediaType.fromFileName("bose.doc").getMimeType());
    MediaContent content = new MediaContent();
    content.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
    content.setMimeType(new ContentType(mediaSource.getContentType()));
    newDocument.setContent(content);

    String gdocsFilename = new String("My Filename");
    newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(gdocsFilename));
    out.println("OK");
    // Push it into Google Docs!! 
    DocumentListEntry uploadedRef = docsService.insert(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"), newDocument);
} catch(Exception e) {
   out.println(e.toString());
} finally {            
    out.close();
}
```

When I run it **locally**, I encounter the following error:

```
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please try again. GDataInvalidEntryExceptionWe're sorry, a server error occurred. Please try again.
```

When i run the version deployed on the Internet ( Jelastic cloud ),
I get this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/data/extensions/QuotaBytesTotal
com.google.gdata.data.docs.MetadataEntry.declareExtensions(MetadataEntry.java:86)
com.google.gdata.data.ExtensionProfile.addDeclarations(ExtensionProfile.java:71)
com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.declareExtensions(BaseFeed.java:235)
com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService.declareExtensions(DocsService.java:171)
com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService.<init>(DocsService.java:108)
bose.google.UploadToDocs.processRequest(UploadToDocs.java:30)
bose.google.UploadToDocs.doGet(UploadToDocs.java:79)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Please get me a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing one of the required dependencies, probably gdata-core-1.0.jar.

Also, check this page for external dependencies: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/java_client_lib

Comment: Thanks for responding .I made sure all of the above are there, Claudio.